# Is there a way to request Stripe for the cancellation reason of a subscription via API?

Tags: api, stripe-payments

I am trying to query stripe for the **cancellation reason** of a subscription to feed this information into our CRM system.

The information I am looking for can be found in the dashboard here:
[Stripe dashboard image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nxvI.png)

I found out that the browser sends a request to *https://dashboard.stripe.com/v1/subscriptions/sub_xxx* but with an API key that seems to belong to user request: *uk_xxx*. When I send a GET request to that endpoint with my API key *sk_live_xxx* I dont get the same data, i.e. the following information is missing:

```
{
    "customer_portal_data": {
        "cancellation_reason": "too_expensive",
        "cancellation_reason_text": null
    }
}
```

My question now: is there a way to query this information via the standard API from stripe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is only available in the Dashboard and Sigma right now and is not available via the API.

Comment: Thanks! We actually now use stripe sigma to pull this information. Hopefully they add it to the API as well so it can be automated via webhook.